# str.format places last variable first in print

Tags: python-3.x

The purpose of this script is to parse a text file (sys.argv[1]), extract certain strings, and print them in columns. I start by printing the header. Then I open the file, and scan through it, line by line. I make sure that the line has a specific start or contains a specific string, then I use regex to extract the specific value.
The matching and extraction work fine.

My final print statement doesn't work properly.

```
import re
import sys

print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format("#query", "target", "e-value",
"identity(%)", "score"))



with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as blastR:
    for line in blastR:
        if line.startswith("Query="):
            queryIDMatch = re.match('Query= (([^ ])+)', line)
            queryID = queryIDMatch.group(1)
            queryID.rstrip
        if line[0] == '>':
            targetMatch = re.match('> (([^ ])+)', line)
            target = targetMatch.group(1)
            target.rstrip
        if "Score = " in line:
            eValue = re.search(r'Expect = (([^ ])+)', line)
            trueEvalue = eValue.group(1)
            trueEvalue = trueEvalue[:-1]
            trueEvalue.rstrip()
            print('{0}\t{1}\t{2}'.format(queryID, target, trueEvalue), end='')
```

The problem occurs when I try to print the columns. When I print the first 2 columns, it works as expected (except that it's still printing new lines):

```
#query  target  e-value identity(%) score
YAL002W Paxin1_129011
YAL003W Paxin1_167503
YAL005C Paxin1_162475
YAL005C Paxin1_167442
```

The 3rd column is a number in scientific notation like 2e-34

But when I add the 3rd column, eValue, it breaks down:

```
#query  target  e-value identity(%) score
YAL002W Paxin1_129011
    4e-43YAL003W    Paxin1_167503
    1e-55YAL005C    Paxin1_162475
    0.0YAL005C      Paxin1_167442
    0.0YAL005C      Paxin1_73182
```

I have removed all new lines, as far I know, using the rstrip() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least three problems:

1) `queryID.rstrip` and `target.rstrip` are lacking closing `()`

2) Something like `trueEValue.rstrip()` doesn't mutate the string, you would need

```
trueEValue = trueEValue.rstrip()
```

if you want to keep the change.

3) This *might* be a problem, but without seeing your data I can't be 100% sure. The `r` in `rstrip` stands for "right". If `trueEvalue` is `4e-43\n` then it is true the `trueEValue.rstrip()` would be free of newlines. But the problem is that your values seem to be something like `\n43-43`. If you simply use `.strip()` then newlines will be removed from either side.

Comment: Yup, that was it! I'm always forgetting how stubborn strings are to changing.